Tensorflow consumes both GPU and CPU Memory
I have TensorFlow set up with GPU enabled on Debian. Upon using  tensorflow.keras.models.load_model to load a model, I noticed that it utilizesoth GPU memory and CPU memory (the system's RAM). I'm curious to know if it's typical for TensorFlow to use some of my system's RAM in addition to GPU memory.

It is normal, not sure why you would think otherwise.

To load smth on GPU you first need to preload this on cpu. Basically SDD -> CPU -> GPU. And of course a lot of times in Python memory management is not very efficient and thus not all CPU objects cleaned on time. Next thing that GPU may offload part of the objects on CPU to process calculations more efficiently. To sum up as was said in previous answer the observed situation is normal. And the question is what you expected to see?

This is not possible to do without being very dependent on the hardware and OS and writing custom CUDA-level code. The usual I/O process is having the CPU moving data from the HDD to the GPU through RAM. To move data directly into the GPU would involve some (tricky) DMA control point from the HDD itself.
